# Sports of western sword fern: descriptions or resources?

Tags: botany, mutations, plant-anatomy

I found a western sword fern (*Polystichum munitum*) growing in a home garden that appears to be showing a sport. Notably, the sportive fronds come off the same rootstock as more normal-appearing fronds (see image).

Prominent features include duplicated frond apices and pinnae, and a "lacy" appearance with marked serrations (see images). There is also possibly some chlorosis and/or necrosis, suggesting that the sportive leaves are unhappy in some way.

Fern sports are a [well-known phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fern_sports), and have been described in the *Polystichum* genus previously.

**Questions:**

1. Is this truly a sport? If not, how could I tell?
2. Are spores from this fern likely to be viable?
3. Is anything known about the mechanism, other than mutation? I know that fern karyotypes and genome sizes can be pretty unwieldy, I suppose ploidy change is a good hypothesis.

[image: duplicated fern apex]
[image: comparison of sport to normal frond on same rootstock]